# Spring - Thymeleaf: Exception processing template

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm following the a book Spring in Action 5th ed., but I believe that is presents a bug.

This is the GitHub of the book. I'm arrived on chap 3 tacos-jdbc
[source of code](https://github.com/habuma/spring-in-action-5-samples)

When submit my order a sudden error appears:

[image]

and in this way on the terminal:

> > 2019-05-25 16:58:18.164 ERROR 11777 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             :
> >     [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-7] Exception processing template
> >     "orderForm": An error happened during template parsing (template:
> >     "class path resource [templates/orderForm.html]")
>
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened
>   during template parsing (template: "class path resource
>   [templates/orderForm.html]")

[image]

OrderController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@SessionAttributes("order")
public class OrderController {

    private OrderRepository orderRepo;

    public OrderController(OrderRepository orderRepo) {
        this.orderRepo = orderRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm() {
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors,
                               SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "orderForm";
        }

        orderRepo.save(order);
        sessionStatus.setComplete();

        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

and orderForm:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${order}">
    <h1>Order your taco creations!</h1>

    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
    <a th:href="@{/design}" id="another">Design another taco</a><br/>

    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
        <span class="validationError">
        Please correct the problems below and resubmit.
        </span>
    </div>

    <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="street">Street address: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{street}"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{city}"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="state">State: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{state}"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="zip">Zip code: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{zip}"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccNumber">Credit Card #: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccNumber}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccNumber')}"
          th:errors="*{ccNumber}">CC Num Error</span>

    <label for="ccExpiration">Expiration: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccExpiration}"/>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccCVV">CVV: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccCVV}"/>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit order"/>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed with this code adding `delivery` prefix:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${order}">
    <h1>Order your taco creations!</h1>

    <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>

    <h3>Your tacos in this order:</h3>
    <a th:href="@{/design}" id="another">Design another taco</a><br/>
    <ul>
        <li th:each="taco : ${order.tacos}"><span th:text="${taco.name}">taco name</span></li>
    </ul>

    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
        <span class="validationError">
        Please correct the problems below and resubmit.
        </span>
    </div>

    <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
    <label for="deliveryName">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryName}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryName')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryName}">Name Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryStreet">Street address: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryStreet}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryStreet')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryStreet}">Street Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryCity">City: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryCity}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryCity')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryCity}">City Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryState">State: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryState}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryState')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryState}">State Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="deliveryZip">Zip code: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{deliveryZip}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('deliveryZip')}"
          th:errors="*{deliveryZip}">Zip Error</span>
    <br/>

    <h3>Here's how I'll pay...</h3>
    <label for="ccNumber">Credit Card #: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccNumber}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccNumber')}"
          th:errors="*{ccNumber}">CC Num Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccExpiration">Expiration: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccExpiration}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccExpiration')}"
          th:errors="*{ccExpiration}">CC Num Error</span>
    <br/>

    <label for="ccCVV">CVV: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{ccCVV}"/>
    <span class="validationError"
          th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccCVV')}"
          th:errors="*{ccCVV}">CC Num Error</span>
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit order"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `th:object="${order}"` in your `orderForm` template but Thymeleaf doesn't know about it.
You have to let Thymeleaf know about this object by passing it to the template like so

```
@GetMapping("/current")
public ModelAndView orderForm() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("orderForm");
    mv.addObject("order", new Order());
    return mv;
}
```

Note: You will have to pass the object from your controller layer at all the places where you are using that object in the template.

---

Update 1

Also update you post method

```
@PostMapping
public ModelAndView processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors,
                           SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("orderForm");
        mv.addObject("order", new Order());
        return mv;
    }

    orderRepo.save(order);
    sessionStatus.setComplete();

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

Comment: same error. If I need to show more classes, let me know

Comment: when you submit an order you will have to add that object in the third line of that method. Because there also you are showing the `orderForm` template that needs an `order` object.

Comment: can you please show me how. I changed as you said, on your first speech.

Comment: first return is an ModelAndView, second one is a String

Comment: Yeah check it again

Comment: @AbdullahKhan don't you loose your _errors_ if you do ```mv.addObject("order", new Order());``` ?

Comment: Yeah he will. He will have to handle error in a better way.

Comment: I'm so sorry, same error again after your update. Anyway thank you. The problem is that this book is full of bugs

Comment: @AbdullahKhan: I put the link to the source code on the main post

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it this way

```
@Controller
public class OrderController {

   @GetMapping("/orders")
   public String orders(Order order) {
      return "orderForm";
   }

   @PostMapping("/orders")
   public String orderForm(@Valid Order order, BindingResult result, Model model) {
       if(result.hasErrors()) {
           return "orderForm";
       } else {
           retrun "your_success_view";   
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I also tried your way, I don't have error on the terminal, but there is a blank page after submit with error, like the first image that I posted, till status 500

Comment: maybe ```@Valid  @ModelAttribute("order") Order order``` in postmapping?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle the display of the validation errors in all the input in the orderForm.html as mentioned in the book as following: (Source Git)

```
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/styles.css}" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <form method="POST" th:action="@{/orders}" th:object="${order}">
      <h1>Order your taco creations!</h1>

      <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}"/>
      <a th:href="@{/design}" id="another">Design another taco</a><br/>

      <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors()}">
        <span class="validationError">
        Please correct the problems below and resubmit.
        </span>
      </div>

      <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}"
            th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <label for="street">Street address: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{street}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('street')}"
            th:errors="*{street}">Street Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <label for="city">City: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{city}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('city')}"
            th:errors="*{city}">City Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <label for="state">State: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{state}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('state')}"
            th:errors="*{state}">State Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <label for="zip">Zip code: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{zip}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('zip')}"
            th:errors="*{zip}">Zip Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <h3>Here's how I'll pay...</h3>
<!-- tag::validatedField[] -->
      <label for="ccNumber">Credit Card #: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{ccNumber}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccNumber')}"
            th:errors="*{ccNumber}">CC Num Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
<!-- end::validatedField[] -->
      <br/>

      <label for="ccExpiration">Expiration: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{ccExpiration}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccExpiration')}"
            th:errors="*{ccExpiration}">CC Num Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <label for="ccCVV">CVV: </label>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{ccCVV}"/>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
      <span class="validationError"
            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('ccCVV')}"
            th:errors="*{ccCVV}">CC Num Error</span>
<!-- tag::allButValidation[] -->
      <br/>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit order"/>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
<!-- end::allButValidation[] -->
```

I think you are not inserting the right information in the form according to validation rules added in the beans as explained in the chapter. By displaying the validation error, you will know exactly which input is not correctly inserted when you submit the order.

---

After investigating your code. The name of attributes in the Order.java are not the same as in the view page orderForm.html

For example, in orderForm the attribute is **name**

```
  <h3>Deliver my taco masterpieces to...</h3>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
```

Whereas in Order.java is **deliveryName**.

```
 @NotBlank(message="Delivery name is required")
    private String deliveryName;
```

The solution is to use the same name of the attribute in the Order.java and orderForm.html page.

Comment: I got the same error. I arrive in a page where I need to click the check box and to put a name for my taco. After submit the order I get the error in the successive page. And the problem isn't related with the validation. 
2019-05-28 21:01:27.110 ERROR 5417 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-8] Exception processing template "orderForm": An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/orderForm.html]")

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during.

Comment: That's weird. Did you update the orderForm.html,  fill the inputs and get parsing error message? Can you add your Order and Taco classes or do you have the source of **your** code in Git? I run the application with the same oderForm.html and I have no errors.

Comment: I will dot it this evening, now I'm at work. Thank you for your help. I can send you the project by email if you want